# Count of deleted entities on app engine using db.delete(iterator_of_keys)

Tags: python, google-app-engine

I find the entities I want to delete:

`to_delete_iterator = models.Foo.all().filter('bar =', baz).run(keys_only = True, batch_size = 1000)`

Then I delete them

`db.delete(to_delete_iterator)`

Which seems to work fine. But I'd like to log the number of entities that I deleted. Is there a way to get that result from `db`? If not, I think my only option is to loop over `to_delete_iterator`, build a list, takes it's length, and then pass that to `db.delete`. Any better options that this?

```
to_delete_keys = []
for key in to_delete_iterator:
  to_delete_keys.append(key)

logging.debug('>> will delete ' + str(len(to_delete_keys)) + ' old entities')   
db.delete(to_delete_keys)
```

Presumably it uses a little more memory than passing the iterator to db.delete, but for keys_only that may not be an issue

Answer (score 0):

Not sure how well this will perform but you could consider using tee.

```
from itertools import tee
k1, k2 = tee(models.Foo.all().filter('bar =', baz).run(keys_only = True, batch_size = 1000)) 

delete_future = db.delete_async(k2)
count = sum(k1)
delete_future.get_result()
```